# How can I convert a normal array of doubles to a guava immutable array

Tags: java, arrays, double, guava

I was just wondering how would i go about converting this:

Into a Google Guava ImmutableDoubleArray.

```
public class Data  {

    private final ImmutableDoubleArray arrays;

    public Data(double[] array)
    {

    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: "convert this" - convert what? I don't see anything that could be converted.

Comment: Btw. Are you sure you want an array of arrays? Because that's what `ImmutableDoubleArray[]` is.

Comment: Apologies, I want to pass a array of doubles to the Data class and it should return an immutable double array object (called arrays)

Comment: https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/ImmutableDoubleArray.html#copyOf-double:A-

Comment: Apologies, no I just want an array that cannot be mutated would you say I am better of using an ImmutableList

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to use `ImmutableDoubleArray` from guava? If not, then just go with `ImmutableList`.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it with Immutable List

Answer (score 1):

```
this.arrays = ImmutableDoubleArray.copyOf(array);
```

Using `ImmutableDoubleArray` is generally preferable to using `ImmutableList`, because it does not come with the overhead of boxing.